# Why is there extra white space on the side of my site?

Tags: css, whitespace

The link to my site is [www.trecall.com](http://www.trecall.com).

On the right side of the site, there is a lot of extra white space.

Can anyone tell me why and how I can get rid of it?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't see any whitespace. Can you add an image?

Answer (score 2):

Your css for header specifies 100% of the parent's width, but gives it a left margin of 165px; this makes the width of the whole page that much wider.